# What is an "unreasonably short leave-pass"?

Tags: exercise, group-rides, organized-rides

I'm reading ["unwritten rules for calling a ride"](http://cyclingtips.com.au/2015/10/the-unwritten-rules-for-calling-a-ride/) and #4 mentions something about "unreasonably short leave-passes". What does that mean?

Comment: Person is only available for a short amount of time. Could be work; but probably wife.

Comment: Just remember "the rules" are amusing and while some of them are serious and useful, some of them are simply silly.

Comment: "Leave pass" is a military term. It basically means permission to take time off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your family or significant other will only give you a few hours *leave*(like Annual leave) from home to go out riding.

Comment: Okay I get it now - it's a "permission slip" for leaving a short time to go riding.

Answer (score 0):

Having such a limited amount of time for a group ride that in order to finish it on time you would need to push group speed up to a point where the ride is not enjoyable or even feasible